# Filter Map by key set

Tags: scala

Is there a shortcut to filter a Map keeping only the entries where the key is contained in a given Set?

Here is some example code

```
scala> val map = Map("1"->1, "2"->2, "3"->3)
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)

scala> map.filterKeys(Set("1","2").contains)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)
```

I am searching for something shorter than this.

Comment: Something shorter than `map.filterKeys(Set("1","2").contains)`? Don't you think that is short and clear enough?

Comment: It's quite clear, but I am searching for something shorter.

Comment: And it can be indeed! See my answer

Comment: *Always* search for something clearer and more understandable for later, when you are skimming your code

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### Answering the Question

You can take advantage of the fact that a `Set[A]` is a predicate; i.e. `A => Boolean`

```
map filterKeys set
```

Here it is at work:

```
scala> val map = Map("1" -> 1, "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3)
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)

scala> val set = Set("1", "2")
set: scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.String] = Set(1, 2)

scala> map filterKeys set
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)
```

Or if you prefer:

```
scala> map filterKeys Set("1", "2")
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)
```

---

### Predicates

It's actually really useful to have some wrapper around a predicate. Like so:

```
scala> class PredicateW[A](self: A => Boolean) {
   | def and(other: A => Boolean): A => Boolean = a => self(a) && other(a)
   | def or(other: A => Boolean): A => Boolean = a => self(a) || other(a)
   | def unary_! : A => Boolean = a => !self(a)
   | }
defined class PredicateW
```

And an implicit conversion:

```
scala> implicit def Predicate_Is_PredicateW[A](p: A => Boolean) = new PredicateW(p)
Predicate_Is_PredicateW: [A](p: A => Boolean)PredicateW[A]
```

And then you can use it:

```
scala> map filterKeys (Set("1", "2") and Set("2", "3"))
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(2 -> 2)

scala> map filterKeys (Set("1", "2") or Set("2", "3"))
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)

scala> map filterKeys !Set("2", "3")
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(1 -> 1)
```

This can be extended to `xor`, `nand` etc etc and if you include symbolic unicode can make for amazingly readable code:

```
val mustReport = trades filter (uncoveredShort ∨ exceedsDollarMax)

val european = { 
  val Europe = (_ : Market).exchange.country.region == Region.EU
  trades filter (_.market ∈: Europe)
}
```

Comment: Your example with the trades filtering is pretty cool. I like the ∈ method, reads just like maths.

Comment: Nice implicit for lifting boolean operations to predicates.  I'll be borrowing that.

Comment: Beware: `filterKeys` result  wraps the original map without copying any elements. This may be a problem for large structures, where you expect the removed elements to be garbage collected later.

Answer (score 9):

Sorry, not a direct answer to your question, but if you know which keys you want to remove (instead of which ones you want to keep), you could do this:

```
map -- Set("3")
```

Comment: `map -- (map.keySet &~ Set("1","2"))` you can always calculate which keys to remove, given you know which keys to keep. (`&~` is "set difference", which is hopefully optimized over `--`)

Comment: @VladPatryshev Care to explain why ?

Comment: @Venkat Sudheer Reddy Aedama, now, 3 year later, I do not see any reason why. I believe I was wrong then.

Answer (score 9):

A tangential tip, in case you are going to follow the `PredicateW` idea in @oxbow_lakes' answer:

In functional programming, instead of defining ad hoc functions, we aim for more generalized and composable abstractions. For this particular case, `Applicative` fits the bill.

`Set` themselves are functions, and the `Applicative` instance for `[B]Function1[A, B]` lets us lift functions to context. In other words, you can lift functions of type `(Boolean, Boolean) => Boolean` (such as `||`, `&&` etc.) to `(A => Boolean, A => Boolean) => (A => Boolean)`. ([Here](http://hseeberger.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/applicatives-are-generalized-functors/) you can find a great explanation on this concept of lifting.)

However the data structure `Set` itself has an `Applicative` instance available, which will be  favored over `[B]Applicative[A => B]` instance. To prevent that, we will have to explicitly tell the compiler to treat the given set as a function. We define a following enrichment for that:

```
scala> implicit def setAsFunction[A](set: Set[A]) = new {
     |   def f: A => Boolean = set
     | }
setAsFunction: [A](set: Set[A])java.lang.Object{def f: A => Boolean}

scala> Set(3, 4, 2).f
res144: Int => Boolean = Set(3, 4, 2)
```

And now put this `Applicative` goodness into use.

```
scala> val map = Map("1" -> 1, "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3)
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)

scala> map filterKeys ((Set("1", "2").f |@| Set("2", "3").f)(_ && _))
res150: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(2 -> 2)

scala> map filterKeys ((Set("1", "2").f |@| Set("2", "3").f)(_ || _))
res151: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)

scala> map filterKeys (Set("2", "3").f map (!_))
res152: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(1 -> 1)
```

Note: All of the above requires Scalaz.