# Filtering out keys while iterating through a map

Tags: scala, dictionary, filter, foreach, iterator

What's the best way to iterate through a map, and filter out certain keys?  The pseudocode might be something like

```
    map.foreach(tuple where !list.contains(tuple._1) => { })
```

Thanks
Bruce

Comment: Do you want to create a new map without those keys, change an existing mutable map by removing those keys, or just doing some action on every key/value except those keys?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral  The last option.  It's a map with a maximum of 2000 total entries, and a maximum of about 20 excluded keys.  The map gets updated frequently (both the excluded and included keys), but I only wish access the included keys for this particular operation.  As such, I would prefer to have a single map for memory and update considerations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter Map by key set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031023/filter-map-by-key-set)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
val m = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 4 -> "c", 10 -> "d")
val s = Set(1,4)
m.filterKeys { s.contains(_) == false }
// Map(2 -> b, 10 -> d)
```

But, if this is a huge map and a huge set, then I'd suggest sorting them first and mutually iterating through them, picking off the bits that you need as you go.  The repeated calls to `contains` may not perform as well as you'd like, especially if you use a `List` instead of a `Set`.

Comment: @Derek Wyatt.  Good point.  Perhaps I should even consider having a second map that excludes the items, since the filtering is going to be the same each time.

Comment: @Bruce Ferguson.  Take what I said with a grain of salt.  Premature optimization is the root of many evils.

Comment: @DerekWyatt.  I hear you.  Thanks for your answer, and the Knuth reminder.

Comment: You can just do `m filterKeys s` if `s` is a Set

Answer (score 4):

```
map.withFilter{tuple => !list.contains(tuple._1)}.foreach{whatever}
```

Equivalently

```
for(tuple <- map if !list.contains(tuple._1)) whatever
```

Comment: This is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

This question has been [asked and answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031023/filter-map-by-key-set/9031524#9031524):

Using the fact that `Set[A]` is a function `A => Boolean`, you can just do:

```
map filterKeys s
```

Comment: Thanks, I looked before submitting, but didn't see this.  Cheers, Bruce

Comment: Except that it's a List, not a Set, and he wants to filter by those NOT in the list